# Fast sorting array by name without one

Tags: javascript

I need sort array by name

```
['b','a' ,'c' ,'e' ,'d' , .....]
```

but I want 'c' push to start in resurt array !

```
['c','a' , 'b' , 'd' ,'e' , ....]
```

How can I do it this?

```
function sortByKey(array, key) {


    return array.sort(function (a, b) {

        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
```

Yes I can delete 'c' from array and add him in final result but I search 
best case

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `Fast Sorting`?

Comment: Basically: `if (a === 'c') { return -1; } else if( b === 'c') { return 1; }`.

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using `String.localeCompare()` function:

```js
var arr = ['b','a' ,'c' ,'e' ,'d'];
arr.sort(function (a,b) {
    return (a == 'c' || b == 'c')? 1 : a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a another array that will allow you to configure `priority` elements and then you can compare values in custom sort function.

**Note:** not sure about `Fast` but this will allow you to sort and make few configurations for priority elements

```js
var data = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
var priority = ['c'];

function getPriority(item) {
  var max_value = 9999999999;
  var index = priority.indexOf(item);
  return index === -1 ? max_value : index
}

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  if ([a, b].some(function(x) {
    return priority.indexOf(x) > -1
  })) {
    return getPriority(a) - getPriority(b);
  } else {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  }
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sortByKey(array) {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a == 'c') {
      return -1;
    } else if (b == 'c') {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    }
  });
}

var data = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']

console.log(sortByKey(data))
```

Comment: I think you mean `'c'` not `c`

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and do something like this :

```js
const items = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
//const items = ['c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e'];

const sortedItems = items.sort(function(a, b) {

  if (a === 'c' || b === 'c') {
    return -2;
  }
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});

console.log(sortedItems)
```

I'd say you should use native stuff all the time as you might get benefits in the future if some engine decides to optimize this method.

Comment: I have updated your answer. Wrapped code in a snippet and fixed OP's input instead of output array. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

**For fastest result by using javascript function**

```js
var fruits = ['b','a' ,'c' ,'e' ,'d'];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
  fruits.sort();
  fruits.splice(2,1);
  fruits.splice(0, 0, 'c');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: When you `splice`, array will rebuilt its index. Please consider that as well in performance.

Comment: use of in built function provide faster execution.so i think not an issue in performance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a special treatment for sorting order of `'c'`, with an object for the sort order and a default value.

This method allows to move another string to the end of the sorting order, with a value of `1` or any greater value than `0`.

```js
var data = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'z'],
    order = { c: -1 };

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0) || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You can move order outside sort as this will hold priority keys and can be used else where. Also you never fails to amaze with you logic. #Respect.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :**

Use array [**sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort the array.

**Step 2 :**

Use array [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the element from an array.

**Step 3 :**

Use array [**unshift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method. It will work as same as array [**push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. The only difference is it adds elements to the beginning of the array instead of the end.

**Working demo :**

```js
var orgArray = ['b','a' ,'c' ,'e' ,'d','c'];
orgArray.sort();
var newArray = orgArray.filter(function(element){
  return element !== "c";
});
newArray.unshift("c");
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You are forgetting, there can be more than 1 `c` in array

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for correcting me !! I updated my answer.